# Из imageView сохранить рисунок в сети

Tags: android, java

Из галереи загружаю рисунок в imageView,  и из imageView надо сохранить рисунов в сети

Выпадает ошибка `java.lang.NullPointerException`. как исправить? надо взять рисунок  `R.id.avka(imageView)`, а не `R.drawable.user2`

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.avka);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();        
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);          
file.saveInBackground();            
ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("ImageUpload");         
imgupload .put("ImageFile", file);          
imgupload.saveInBackground();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avka);

```
                    picView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    picView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bm = picView.getDrawingCache();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```